# How to specify the latest album in a images view?

Tags: 6, media

I am using node galleries. I've created a view where I display all the images that are of type "gallery_image". The problem is, I need to now get it to only show me the values for a specific album, where the specific album is whatever is the most recently created album.

So in this image:

[image]

First prize would've been if I could say:

```
operator : is equal to : value
```

And make the value something like [[LATEST_ALBUM]] and have that somehow magically figure it out. It would be easy to do if I could add PHP there.

Any ideas how to get around this?

Answer (score 0):

I just ended up using "arguments" with a default PHP argument if one is not specified. The PHP code:

```
$res = db_query("select nid from node where type  = 'node_gallery_gallery' order by nid desc limit 1");
$res = db_fetch_object($res);
return $res->nid;
```

Works beautifully. Only side effect being that anyone that can access this view, can view other galleries using a parameters. But in my case that's not a problem.